# A deprecation warning keeps popping up in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, warnings

So, I'm making a game that I am having multiple problems with as it is my first one. One of the problem is that whenever I open it only a -5 pops up and then the program starts working. I think this is because of this specific warning below:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/Everything Here!!/MoreCollision.py", line 57
    win.blit(text, (250 -(text.get_width()/2), 200))
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
```

And the code belonging to it is:

```
 def hit(self):
        self.x = 60
        self.y = 410
        self.walkCount = 0
        font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 100)
        text = font1.render('-5', 1, (255,0,0))
        win.blit(text, (250 -(text.get_width()/2), 200))
        pygame.display.update()
        i = 0
        while i < 300:
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            i += 1
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    i = 301
                    pygame.quit()
```

So, I really have no clue how to fix it. Please help if anyone can.

Comment: You should change that line to `win.blit(text, (250 -int(text.get_width()/2), 200))`. However, this probably is not the cause of your problem. Where does a negative 5 pop up? In the terminal, pygame window, or somewhere else?

Comment: @Seth The negative 5 pops up right in the middle of the screen and the whole background goes black while it is not supposed to do any of this. And when my character in the game collides with the enemy everything workd fine until it starts again and the character just goes real down in the pygame window. Do you want me to upload the whole code?

Comment: Your code reads `text = font1.render('-5', 1, (255,0,0))`, so that is going to show a -5 on-screen when blitted. What did you expect?

Comment: @Seth how should I fix it? I'm sorry I am a total beginner

Comment: Remove the part of the code that writes a -5 to the screen...

Comment: Great! I would appreciate if you could upvote and mark as accepted my answer :)

Comment: @Seth my words expressing the issue were not clear at all (this coud be bc my native language isn't english). Your code did help but not in the way I intended it to, so I will just post another nice and clear question. And I am very sorry for the inconvinience I caused you ...

Answer (score 0):

The warning is related to the coordinate argument of [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). Floating point coordinates, would mean that the origin of the [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is somewhere in between to pixels in the window. That doesn't make much sense. The coordinates are automatically, implicitly truncated and that is indicated by the warning.

Use eiter the `//` (floor division) operator

```py
win.blit(text, (250 -(text.get_width() // 2), 200))
```

or [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to integral values

```py
win.blit(text, (250 - round(text.get_width()/2), 200))
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still not going away.

Comment: @BruceBanner I'm sorry, so you did it wrong.

Comment: @BruceBanner Your question is about the warning *"an integer is required (got type float)"*. This question is duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry I am a total beginner.

Comment: I think this was my fault because my question was very unclear, and yes you're right that I want to dislay the -5 but only when my character collides with the enemy, but it is showing it at the starting of my programme which is not what it is supposed to do. I'm very sorry for all this misunderstanding, and I will be posting a new and clear question...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code that writes `-5` to the screen to stop it from writing to the screen. This also solves the `DeprecationWarning` since it was caused by the code that writes `-5` to the screen!

Comment: The deprecate waring is caused by the line `win.blit(text, (250 -(text.get_width()/2), 200))`, as clearly shown in the error trace. It is caused by the fact that the result of a division is always a floating point number

Comment: Yes but that is writing `-5` to the screen which the OP doesn't want. Deleting the line entirely solves both problems. @Rabbid76

Comment: So you want delete the line `win.blit(text, (250 -(text.get_width()/2), 200))`?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the comments on the question, you will see that this solved the OP's problem. @Rabbid76

Comment: No I don't think so. I'm very sure he wants to draw some text. I think deleting all t he code is not the solution. However, the question is completely unclear and needs to be improved.